# Android Thread makes the UI blank screen

Tags: android, multithreading

I have written a `Thread` in my application. When the thread starts running, the UI screen becomes blank. How to can I avoid this?

```
public class SetTickerText extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            SystemClock.sleep(25000);
            Log.i("Map", "after wait");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you starting the thread?

Comment: by calling it from the OnCreate method.  m_SetTickerText.run();

Comment: You need to call thread.start, not the run function directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be something like (don't have a compiler near me):

```
new SetTickerText().start()
```

Essentially, when you tell the thread object to start, it spins up the new thread, which then invokes run for you.  What you're doing is calling run from the UI thread, just like any other function, so it's blocking your UI thread from returning

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is using SystemClock.sleep. This method will force the CPU going into deep thead. What you want to do is to sleep the current thread which is done using Thread.sleep: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I have called

```
thread.run()
```

instead of

```
thread.start()
```

by mistake.

For more details follow,

https://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/why-dont-we-call-run-method-directly-why-call-start-method/